# How to create multiconfigured matrix project with google api on Jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, google-api, emulation

I am trying to configure matrix project to run my apk on different emulator configuration but when I tryied to use **"Google Inc.:Google APIs:16"** as my os target the project was not build. when I try to build on Android 4.1 it works, but I need to use google api to run monkey on it. What should I input to matrix with os parameter to create emulator with google API
??

> Triggering ldpi,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,WVGA ldpi,Google Inc.:Google
>   APIs:16,WVGA completed with result FAILURE

- > java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs:
  >   ...\MatrixProject\density\ldpi\os\Google Inc.:Google
  >   APIs:16\resolution\WVGA   at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:973)
  >     at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1323)
  >     at
  >   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
  >     at
  >   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
  >     at
  >   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
  >     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1516)  at
  >   hudson.matrix.MatrixRun.run(MatrixRun.java:146)   at
  >   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
  >     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236) [FINDBUGS] Skipping
  >   publisher since build result is FAILURE

Comment: Generally that should work. Can you elaborate on "was not built"? What was the output of the Jenkins build?

Comment: Triggering ldpi,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,WVGA
ldpi,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,WVGA completed with result FAILURE-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're using Windows, which doesn't support filenames with colons in them, and so Jenkins is failing when trying to create a unique directory for each build combination.

Currently your OS version axis contains values like "`Google Inc.:Google APIs:16`", and the "Android OS" field probably contains something like "`${os}`".

Instead, try changing the axis to contain only the API levels, e.g. "`16`", and change the "Android OS" field to be "`Google Inc.:Google APIs:${os}`".

That way, the directory names created by Jenkins won't contain colons.

Comment: That's clever! I had a similar issue on a Linux server because of the space in the folder name, but your solution solved it